# How to make php ajax html email sending mechanism in BootStrap 3?

Tags: php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have tried the following and I am unable to send the email still. My hosting provider permits phpmail as I get email from my other Joomla websites easily on this hosting.

Now here goes the public.html file:

```
   <html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitForm(){
        var formName=document.forms["contact-us"];
        var name=formName.elements["name"].value;
        var email=formName.elements["email"].value;
        var msg=formName.elements["msg"].value;
        var phone = formName.elements["phone"].value;
        if(name=='' || email=='' || msg=='' || phone=='')
            alert("Please Input all fields");
        else
        {
            var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&msg1='+ msg + '&phone1='+ phone;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"index.php",
                data:dataString,
                cache:false,
                success: function(){
                    alert("Email Sent Successfully!");  
                }
            });     
        }
        return false;
    }
    function Validate()
    {
        var stop=false;
        var x=document.forms["contact-us"]["email"].value;
        var p=document.forms["contact-us"]["phone"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(isNaN(p)){
            alert("Please enter your correct phone number without '+' or '-'");
            stop=true;
        }else{
            var temp = Number(p);
            if(temp == 0){
                alert("Please provide a valid number.");
                stop=true;
            }
        }
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
        {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address!");
            stop=true;
        }
        if(stop){
            return false;
        }
        else
            return submitForm();
    }

</script>

</body>

    </html>
```

and then I have some code in index.php file to deal with it. Here it goes:

```
<?php
if ($dataString)
 {
    $recipient = $_GET['sagar@sagaryadav.com'];
    $sender = $_GET'[Avighna Website'];
    $body = $_GET["$dataString"];
    $headers = 'From: info@avighnamerchandising.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@avighnamerchandising.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(5.5.31);
    $sendMail = mail($recipient, $sender, $body, $headers);
 }
?>
```

Now, what's wrong. Why am I not able to send this email from the form and what is it that needs to be there in the index.php file that would make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($_POST['dataString']) { 
$recipient =$_POST['email1'];               $sender = 'Avighna Website'; 
 $body = $_POST['msg1']; 
 $headers = 'From: info@avighnamerchandising.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@avighnamerchandising.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(5.5.31);
 $sendMail = mail($recipient,       $sender, $body, $headers); } ?>
```

You are using the post method nit get method

Comment: I did edit the php file and made it like you recommended sir. And then again - the mystery continues - it doesn't send me email from this contact form.

Comment: Still doesn't work sir. There seems to be a bigger mystery, I think something to do with dataString variable